# Python3, Gtk3, Glade, set label color from code

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, glade

I have a Glade file with a label with a gray default color, 
which I want to override with green from code.

Therefore I added a style class in Glade:

[image: glade part]

and added this to my Python script:

[image: python part]

However, the color remains gray.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that Glade initially preceded the style class name with a dot in its generated XML file (see screenshot in the OP).

You need to edit the Glade XML file and remove it:

[image]

After that, you can repeatedly change the style class name in the Glade GUI, it does not get a dot again.

Answer (score 0):

I made it a bit differently.

in a fileforcolors.css

I included

```
#resetstddata_button {
    background: #00BFFF;
}
```

where the "resetstddata_button" is the name of the widget in the glade file (open the glade editor, click on the GtkButton you want to change the color, page "common", you see the parameter entry "Widget name", put the "resetstddata_button" in it ).

The python3 code extract for this button color change is:

```
style_provider = gtk.CssProvider()
css = open('/home/fileforcolors.css',
           'rb')  # rb needed for python 3 support

css_data = css.read()
css.close()
style_provider.load_from_data(css_data)
gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(gdk.Screen.get_default(), style_provider,
                                         gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thanks, @floppy_molly, for your valuable contribution. It did not make a difference, but it brought another train of thought to me. After some hoops and loops I got to the problem, for which I am going to make an answer.

Comment: I forgot an important topic: this button is in an eventbox which is colored. The button was simply half-transparent to let the color going through.          self.eventbox_exitbutton.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(1, 0, 0, 1))  =  my previous answer was only 20% of the answer (I am reading some old code and forgot the whole story). So, create an eventbox. make it colored. put a button in it (play with transparency), an you will have a bit color.